# UITextField in UITableView to becomeFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextview

I have a problem which I dont have a clue how to work around. Maybe anyone of you could help me to the correct directions...

Simple I have a UITableView with each cell containing a UITextField.   When I´m editing a cell (UITextField) and hit Return Key, a new row is inserted under the current cell.  After that I reloadData on the TableView, the new row is showed. Everything is OK here.

Now to my problem,  I want to [UITextField becomeFirstResponder] on the newest added row.  But I could not find anyway to accomplish this.  I could post code but didn't find that necessary.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should somehow be able to get the indexPath of the last inserted row. If you have this indexPath you can call the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method of the tableView.

Now you have the last inserted cell and can call the becomeFirstResponder method of the textfield (do you have a custom made cell?).

Comment: Yes I have a custom made cell.  Your info was brilliant.  Ty for that!